# Magento 2 - change the form fields sort order in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

How can i change the sort order of the field in the shipping form at checkout. In the `checkout_index_index.xml` there is only option to sort the region, city, company, etc. But not:

Name, Surname, Suffix, Prefix

thx for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) XML Layout:

We should use `<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>`

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">21</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2) Or, Plugin for the `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process` method

```
public function aroundProcess($subject, \Closure $proceed, $jsLayout)
{

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
    ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
    ['children']['lastname']['sortOrder'] = 20;
    ......

    $customJsLayout = $proceed($jsLayout);

    return $customJsLayout;
}
```

We can see more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

Comment: thanks khoa, with your solution i can sort fields like firstname, name ... the prefix and suffix fields are not working

Comment: ahh, i had an typo mistake in my xml, its working, great!

Comment: there is an special case with street[0], which is not working via xml, do you have any idear what the correct syntax is?

Comment: Yes, @FlorinP. I faced the same issue with street. I tried with **Plugin way** - the second way. Tomorrow, I will test again with Layout xml.

Comment: ok, its the last piece in order to make it work

Comment: is there for the billing form on next step the same procedure?

Comment: Seem that we can use Plugin way. Find the `additional-fieldsets` in `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::processPaymentConfiguration` method.

Comment: @FlorinP. you catch a good case. Tomorrow, I will investigate more time and update my answer again.

Comment: Seem that I was wrong when using after Plugin, we should use **around Plugin**.

Comment: Ok @KhoaTruongDinh it would be great to clarify this. What's the difference between after and around plugin?

Comment: hey @Khoa, i tried it with via Plugin and i can not bring it up to work, could you paste your test code in here?

Comment: You tried with **around Plugin**? I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, with around, after, both of them. Im not sure if my code is correct, a sample would be nice

Comment: See my gist: https://gist.github.com/mrkhoa99/15c6e83ffbe4ddb3805d51a777390a30. You can comment on my Gist.

Comment: i had no di.xml - its working on shipping form with around plugin

Comment: Did you check the billing form? It should be the same with shipping form.

Comment: Yes I checked, has no effect to the billing form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58800/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-florin-p).

Answer (score 1):

the layout xml is not working because of wrong path

Use insted of

```
app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

this

```
app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

And you have to replace this:

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
```

with this

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
```

Then it will work perfectly

Comment: Hi @Likeweb the above answer is not working with custom field in checkout page