# How to change order of form fields in the checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, sort

I want to change the order of form fields in the checkout page.I want to reorder these inout fields
[image]
I referred this link [Magento 2 - change the form fields sort order in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174052/magento-2-change-the-form-fields-sort-order-in-checkout?rq=1) but I am getting blank checkout page after adding this field.

my

> theme/name/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="motobatt_header"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And I edited this code by

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="motobatt_header"/>

        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1001</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1003</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And now I am getting a blank page

Comment: Code looks fine. I have checked it in my local system and it works.

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes. the code is working fine now but now getting another issue. I am not able to order the street address. I added this <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">16000</item>
                </item>